# getting controller return type error in playframework when trying to return Future[Result]

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, concurrent.futures

I have a pretty complex flow of my controller, this is how it goes using words:

```
- get the request 

- translate it to my model
  case it succeed: 
      insert some record to my db
         case it succeed:
            perform some api call
               case it succeed:
                  match its returned value 
               case failed:
         recover with proper result
         case failed:
            recover with proper result
  case failed:
     recover with proper result
```

but in my code i get some error that somewhere im not returning Future of Result properly...

the error:

> expression of type unit doesnt conform to expected type
>   Future[Result]

this is the code:

```
def myApiMethod ...

    val requestAsModel = request.body.extractOpt[MyModel]

    requestAsModel match {
      case Some(req) =>
        // returning Future
        dbService.insert.onComplete {
          case Success(x) =>
            myApiService.doSomething(req).map {
              case good: GoodRes => Ok(Extraction.decompose(good))
              case bad: BadRes => BadRequest(Extraction.decompose(bad))
            } recover {
              case ex =>
                InternalServerError
            }
          case Failure(ex) => Future {InternalServerError}
        }
      case None =>
        Future.successful(BadRequest("not a good body content"))
    }
}
```

so you see the problem here?

and does it looks like a good practice for the controller to be written this way?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Future *onComplete* method returns Unit [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.concurrent.Future).
You need to replace *onComplete* with *flatMap* call to be able to transform resulting future to Future[Result]:

```
    dbService.insert.flatMap{
        case Success(x) => 
              myApiService.doSomething(req).map {
                  case good: GoodRes => Ok(Extraction.decompose(good))
                  case bad: BadRes => BadRequest(Extraction.decompose(bad))
             } recover {
              case ex =>
                InternalServerError
            }
        case Failure(ex) => Future {InternalServerError}
    }
```

I suggest to read this article [Scala Futures guide](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html). Especially part about composing futures.